# Copy a hyperlink via Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hyperlink, copy

I am trying to figure out how to copy a hyperlink via visual basic.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Search.Tick
    If Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        PageText = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
        If InStr(PageText, SearchText) > 0 Then
            Search.Enabled = False
            isThere()
        Else
            WebBrowser1.Refresh()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So I got that there, and once the "searchText" is found on the webpage, I want to copy the hyperlink associated with it. Once that text is found it WILL have a hyperlink attached to it, and I dont know how to copy it.

Comment: I have it so that that loops until the text is found.  The "PageText" var is the page text and the "SearchText" var is what ever the user enters in as what is being searched on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make use of the HtmlAgilityPack, available [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).
Using this, you could then use an XPath query to obtain the hyperlink, based on it's text.

This example gets the URL for the "Ask Question" hyperlink at the top of the StackOverflow home page by name:

```
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml)
Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[text()=""Ask Question""]")
Dim attr As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute = node.Attributes("href")
Dim url As String = attr.Value
```

Also, as an aside, the HtmlAgilityPack has the ability to load documents directly from a URL, meaning that you wouldn't have to use the WebBrowser control, unless you otherwise need to.

```
Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: OK, I have never actually downloaded extra packs for Visual Basic, so when I download this where do I copy the files to.

Comment: After downloading, you will have to select the DLL for the version of the framework you are using.  Copy the DLL from that folder into your project folder.  Then, in Visual Studio add that file as a reference.

Comment: OK, when I tested this, I got an error on this line. It said "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Dim attr As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute = node.Attributes("href")

Sorry, I dont know much about HTML at all.

Comment: Although I did edit a line, because it is not always going to be one single string.

Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[text()=" + SearchText + "]")

Comment: You need the quotes to be included, so it'll need to look more like this: Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[text()=""" & SearchText & """]")

Comment: Oh OK, I see, that makes sense, I was just over looking that. But on the next line, after it found the item, it says, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", and the line is 
Dim attr As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute = node.Attributes("href")

Again, I am sorry, I feel like you are just babying me through this because I dont know enough about HTML.

Comment: No worries.  The "Object reference..." error is most likely because 'node' is Nothing, meaning it didn't find a hyperlink with 'SearchText' as its exact text.
So as in the example, here is the target hyperlink from the S.O. 'Ask Question' link:
  <a href="/questions/ask" id="nav-askquestion">Ask Question</a>
What the XPath query does is say, find an anchor tag with 'Ask Question' as its exact text, then from there get its 'href' attribute.  If the link you're after isn't in this form, then you would need to modify the XPath query.

Comment: OK, so I see what I was doing. I was typing in a keyword to locate it. Lets say I wanted to search for "Holiday Fedora" I typed in 'Holiday" thinking it would find that and take the kyperlink from it. It works, but I am going to try to modify it to get the substring and find "Holiday" so I dont have to type it in exactly.